# Unable to edit the "id" field in in a qgis shapefile layer (but everything else seems to work)

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to create a polygon shapefile layer in QGIS (2.12.1).  Because I will be creating many polygons I'm not going to be able to maintain a unique id number manually (without keeping track of it on a piece of paper or something, which is exactly the sort of thing these fancy computers were supposed to replace).

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis) to automatically assign an id after the fact, but every attempt I make to edit the "id" column fails to persist.  As soon as I save the edits (or just try sorting the attribute table on the id column or something) everything reverts to `NULL`.

I see the same behavior in 2.12.0 as well.

Is this supposed to work?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: for starters, why do you want unique ids? Can you make any edits to any other field?

Comment: In ArcGIS, the ID field is a phantom, reserved for the row identifier (physical record number and *immutable*). It's hard to imagine that QGIS didn't take this into account. Name the field anything legal other than "ID" and your procedure might work...

Comment: I want unique ids so that I have some way to reference the polygons in queries/filters/etc.  I suspect that @vince is on to something, because I can create and or edit other fields without a problem...it's just the "id" field that behaves oddly.  Maybe this is just a shapefile oddity.

Comment: Shapefiles do not have persistent ids. When you open a shapefile the first feature has id=0 and the next ones 1,2,3... If you delete feature id=2 from the middle, after saving and reopening features are reordered and what used to be id=3 is now id=2. You must create your own id "my_id" as a normal attribute and try to deal with it.

Comment: How you describe it, it should work. This is what I can think of:
- Did you set the attribute type to a numeric type (no text)?
- Did you set the layer to editable?
- Do you have the layer/file open in an other application?

Comment: @user30184 you should post that as an answer.