# Manually digitalize points in QGIS with automatic ID

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point

I would like to create a few thousand points by clicking on specific points in my background map.
I have created a shapefile-layer for this task. But when I click on the map, QGIS always asks for a point ID. Is it possible to give these points an ID automatically so I don't have to type one? Do the points need an ID? If I just click enter, the point is saved without an ID. Is that a problem?

Comment: potential duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-a-way-of-auto-increment-for-the-id-column-in-qgis/312406#312406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `attribute form` tab of the layer properties to set a default value for newly generated features (where the red text is in the old screenshot I attached). If you enter `$id` there, every new feature will be assigned a unique ID upon creation.

And no, unless you're working with geopackages, your features don't need an ID.

[image]

---

Alternatively you may disable the attribute form when creating new features in the `digitizing` tab in the options.

Answer (score 3):

It's not per se a problem, if you don't enter an ID, since your location is still a unique identifier. But of course this would be bad style and could get you into problems in the workflow later on. So an unique ID is almost certainly a must.

But your question has been answered previously, and extensively. In my opinion the most straight forward way would be using the 'Attributes Form' in the layer properties, explained e.g. here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312406/176374

If I missunderstand your question and you have a different need please correct me.