# Shortest path points layer to points layer

Tags: qgis, shortest-path

i'd like to know how can i get in QGIS the shortest path from a points layer to points layer, according to field values. In QGIS, I've seen only the function "from vector to single point" and i need "from vector to vector" based on field values (field A).
For example, the expected output:

[image]

[image]

Which geoprocessing, in QGIS, should i use to get the output layer in one shot?

Answer (score 2):

If your points are drawn in your desired order (fid) then it's very simple using the `points to path` tool. If your data is like the screenshot, you don't need the `field A`, and using the id order you have everything should be fine and you should get your desired output.

If your IDs are not sorted correctly, first you need to re-order them using [this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/132859/103942), and then use the `points to path` tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Using "points to path" i get the shortest path among start points, and not the paths following the route layer, reaching the correspoding end point.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not creating new connections, but creating a path using existing connections/line network. Thus this is a classical routing/network task. In QGIS, under Menu Processing > Toolbox > Network, you find [several `Shortest path` algorithms](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html) for that. There is no algorithm for layer to layer tasks, but you can easily overcome this limitation by using [batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html).

1. Open Shortest path (layer to point) algorithm and click batch mode.
2. For End point, click on Autofill... > Add values by Expression and use this expression:  `aggregate ('end_layer', 'array_agg', $geometry)`
3. Fill in the first row for all other inputs and use Autofill... > Fill down to copy them to the other rows.
4. In the resulting layers, delete those connections you don't need:, e.g. keep only the lines with attribute `A` = 1 and delete those with `A` = 2.
   *For a bit more sophisticated solution, where only the correct connections (start1/end1) are created, see below.*

[image]

##### Variant: creating only the correct connections

If you have a lot of different values for your attribtue `A`, you don't want to create unnecessary connections that you have to delete afterwards. In this case, with a bit more complex variant, you can only connect start-points 1 with end points 1, start points 2 with end points 2 etc.

1. Split your start layer with [Split Vector Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) algorithm, based on attribute `A` and be sure to have a consistent naming of the layers - here I use `start_1`, `start_2` etc.
2. Run Shortest path (layer to point) in batch mode as above
3. To add the vector layers with start points, use Autofill > Add Values by Expression with this expression to load all layers whosw name begin with `start`

   ```
    array_filter(
        array_foreach(
            @map_layers ,
            case 
            when left (layer_property (@element, 'name'),5) = 'start'  -- here you define the conditions which layers should be considered: in this case all layers with a name that starts with the 5 characters "start"
            then @element 
            end
        ), @element is not NULL
    )
   ```
4. To add the vector layers with end points, use `Autofill... > Calculate by Expression` (attention: this time donf't select `Add Values by Expression`!) and insert this expression to get the end point with attribute value (number) corresponding to the number contained in the name of the input layer - so `start_1` layer will connect to point feature with attribute `A` = 1 etc.:

   ```
    geometry(
        get_feature(
            'end',  -- layer name
            'A',  -- attribute name
            regexp_matches (layer_property (@START_POINTS, 'name') , '(\\d)')[0]
        )
    )
   ```

The variable `@START_POINTS` is created automatically, based on the input you made in the start field.

*Result, without showing the initial route/network layer for clarity:*

[image]